# Is the phrase "even know" in place of "even though they know" valid in any known regional dialect?

Tags: phrases

My friend will use the phrase "even know" in place of "even though `I/he/they` know" or "even knowing" and is adamant it is a valid phrase where she comes from.  For example:

> The cop gave me a parking ticket even know parking is free on Sundays.

I have never heard of it, but I was wondering if anybody here has.

Comment: I suspect that you are hearing him say ***even though*** rather than ***even know.***

Comment: even knowing ...

Comment: Sounds like an eggcorn to me.

Comment: Where does your friend come from?